# change the $content_width

Tags: images, child-theme, content-width

I am creating a child theme based on 2016

I want to set new upload media images

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'azm_add_image_size' );
function azm_add_image_size() {
  add_image_size( 'helen', 936 ); 
  add_image_size( 'brian', 227 ); 
}


add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );
function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
       'helen' => __( 'helen' ),
        'brian' =>__( 'brian')
    ) );
}
```

The small size, brian, works fine.

However the large size is creating the correct image in the uploads folder eg 'bluehousefrontelevation-1-936x624.jpg'

however, in the backend the media library is showing helen-840x560 and it adds the wrong width/height sizes into the code.

I have tired suggestions at https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width and [core ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21256)

Nothing seems to work.

The only way i can find to get round it is to edit the `functions.php` within 2016 - which obviously I don't really want to do - here's what i edit:

```
function twentysixteen_content_width() {
//  $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'twentysixteen_content_width', 840 );
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'twentysixteen_content_width', 2000 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentysixteen_content_width', 0 );
```

Is there are better way to change this (annoying) variable please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there are better way to change this (annoying) variable please?

The *Twenty Sixteen* theme provides you with the `twentysixteen_content_width` filter, where the default is `840`.

To modify it you should be able to use this within your child theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'twentysixteen_content_width', function( $content_width )
{
    // Override the default 840 content width
    $content_width = 2000;

    return $content_width; 
} );
```

Comment: great - thanks - I knew there had to be a way, I just couldn't find it. So thanks a million